# Anything other than the variable Python

Tags: python

I am very much new to Python and basically want anything other than d or o to rerun the question? Any help?

```
Myfile = raw_input( '''Specify filename (o) or use default chain (d)? ''')


if Myfile == 'd':
    print 'default choosen '
    Myfile = 'M:/test/testchains_a.csv'


if Myfile == 'o':
    print 'own file choosen '
    Myfile = raw_input('Enter absolute path to the .csv file:')

else:
    print 'successful'
```

Comment: The `print 'successful'` happens whenever `MyFile != 'o'`. Is that actually what you want here? If not, when is it _supposed_ to happen?

Comment: A few side notes: You usually want to name variables in lowercase (`myfile`). Also, it's a bit confusing to reuse the same variable for the selection and the actual path. Also, be consistent with your spacing—especially with actual printouts to the user (e.g., you've got a space after the `?` in the first `raw_input`, but not after the `:` in the second), but also in your code—e.g., don't put a space inside the parens for `raw_input`. That will make your code more readable, when it gets more complicated. Finally, you don't need `'''` for single-line strings, just use `'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this the way `squiguy` suggested, but it might be more readable to put the whole thing into a loop, so you don't have to repeat the same checks twice:

```
while True:
    Myfile = raw_input( '''Specify filename (o) or use default chain (d)? ''')

   if Myfile == 'd':
        print 'default choosen '
        Myfile = 'M:/test/testchains_a.csv'
        break

    elif Myfile == 'o':
        print 'own file choosen '
        Myfile = raw_input('Enter absolute path to the .csv file:')
        break
```

This will loop forever, until it hits a `break`—in other words, until they select `'d'` or `'o'`.

Comment: @squiguy: I'm not sure which is nicer. If there were 20 cases, I'd definitely go this way—but with just 2, your may be more pythonic.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `while` loop to check whether or not the input is and 'o' or a 'd':

```
MyFile = None
while MyFile != 'o' and MyFile != 'd':
  Myfile = raw_input( '''Specify filename (o) or use default chain (d)? ''')
```

Comment: +1. But you need to set `MyFile = None` or something similar first, otherwise you'll get a `NameError`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop:

```
wrong = True
while(wrong):
    file = raw_input("My awesome prompt")
    if file == "d":
        file = '/some/path'
        wrong = False
    if file == "o":
        file = raw_input("Where?")
        wrong  = False

# Continue your program...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your actual problem here is bad UI design. The first question is superfluous and can be easily eliminated:

```
myfile = raw_input('Enter absolute path to the .csv file (leave blank to use the default):')
myfile = myfile or 'M:/test/testchains_a.csv'
```

This "hit enter to use the default" approach is quite common in dialogue programs.

To answer the question *as asked*, I'd suggest using a function like this:

```
def prompt(message, choices):
    while True:
        s = raw_input(message)
        if s in choices:
            return s
```

and in your main code:

```
option = prompt('Specify filename (o) or use default chain (d)? ', 'od')
if option == 'd':
    ...
elif option == 'o':
    ...
```

Comment: Andif the answers would be `yes` and `no` you could just do `prompt("?", ("yes", "no"))`, got my +1

Answer (score 0):

use elif (elseif) and else

```
file = input("enter (d) to use the default file or enter (c) to specify a custom path: ")
if file.lower() == "d":
    print("some code")
elif file.lower() == "c":
    print("some code")
else:
    print("invalid answer!")
    input()
```